# How to map to a composite key in JPA

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm

I have a composite ID defined in a JPA entity, Entity A. In a different entity, Entity B, I have a `@ManyToOne` annotation back to Entity A. I am trying to use `@JoinColumns` in Entity B, specifying both the columns that make up the composite key in Entity A.

In EntityB, I have:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name="Column1", referencedColumnName = "Column1"),
    @JoinColumn(name="Column2", referencedColumnName = "Column2")
})
private EntityA entityA;
```

I keep getting this exception:

```
EntityA not mapped to a single property
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post both classes? Do you have extra @Id tags floating around causing confusion?

Answer (score 1):

You would need to include the EntityA and the composite id class to your question, but generally speaking your on the right path, the following is an analogous working example, maybe it'll be helpfull

```
@NotNull
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumns({
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITYA_PARTA",
                referencedColumnName = "PARTA"),
    @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITYA_PARTB",
                referencedColumnName = "PARTB")
})
protected EntityA entityA;
```

and EntityA

```
@Entity
public class EntityA {

    @EmbeddedId
    protected EntityId id;
```

and EntityId

```
@Embeddable
public class EntityId implements Serializable {

    protected String partA;

    protected String partB;

    protected EntityId() {
    }
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing but I still see the same exception. It must be some other problem.

Comment: Given that you are doing it correctly, you can also get this error as a result of a typo ... ie the referencedColumnName has a different name in the entity. Double check your referenced columns are in fact column1 and column2